# Get only a sample of a DataFrame with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have a DataFrame, which has two columns `content` and `target`.
The DataFrame is 1.000.000 rows long and this is the distribution for the target:

- Target = 0 (100.000)
- Target = 1 (400.000)
- Target = 2 (500.000)

I need to get the same number of target values in the DataFrame, so I'm using `sample()` to get only a fixed number of rows that has target o `x`, this is the code I'm using:

```
samples = 100000
dataset[dataset['target'] == 0] = dataset[dataset['target'] == 0].sample(n=samples, axis=0)
dataset[dataset['target'] == 1] = dataset[dataset['target'] == 1].sample(n=samples, axis=0)
dataset[dataset['target'] == 2] = dataset[dataset['target'] == 2].sample(n=samples, axis=0)
```

If after the execution I access `dataset[dataset['target'] == 2]` for example, it will return a shape of (100000, 2) but accessing `dataset` only returns the **exact** same dataset as before, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are sampling fewer samples in each `Target`, you can use `groupby().sample`:

```
# random_state for repeatability. Remove if needed
dataset = dataset.groupby('target').sample(n=samples, random_state=42)
```